how to create a new project which contains a App.js in React Native
when I create a new project in React Native a default tsx file is created as the entry point. But I want to create a new app which has a App.js file as my main entry point. How?
I tried this command but it didnt work
npx create-expo-app AwesomeProject

You can just rename the file to App.jsx. Do the same for any new component you create.

that did not work, I renamed the index.tsx file and it broke everything
